# XLST Combine Sibling Nodes into 1 Record

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, filemaker, xslt-grouping

Trying to learn how to use XLS/XLST for importing data into Filemaker.  I have the very basics down, but now I need optimization.

Currently I have about 11 sets of data splintered into siblings I need to combine into a single record during the import process. Right now, I use 11 separate xsl files to import the data in 11 separate imports with each file focusing on a specific set of data (fire count, hit count, score, etc).  This is terribly inefficient, but I lack the know-how to work in more detail with XLST and combine the fragmented data into one record.

An example of the data I'm working with is as follows:

```
<character_list limit="0" returned="2" milliseconds="0">
<character id="5428010618020696081" active_profile_id="15" faction_id="3" head_id="1" title_id="0">
<stats>
<weapon_stat_list>
<weapon_stat item_id="25003" last_save="1354544215" last_save_date="2012-12-03 14:16:55.0" stat_name="weapon_fire_count" value="108" vehicle_id="0"/>
<weapon_stat item_id="25003" last_save="1354544215" last_save_date="2012-12-03 14:16:55.0" stat_name="weapon_hit_count" value="60" vehicle_id="0"/>
<weapon_stat item_id="125" last_save="1354564613" last_save_date="2012-12-03 19:56:53.0" stat_name="weapon_fire_count" value="7708" vehicle_id="0"/>
<weapon_stat item_id="125" last_save="1354564613" last_save_date="2012-12-03 19:56:53.0" stat_name="weapon_play_time" value="13406" vehicle_id="0"/>
<weapon_stat item_id="125" last_save="1354564613" last_save_date="2012-12-03 19:56:53.0" stat_name="weapon_score" value="62012" vehicle_id="0"/>
<weapon_stat item_id="1259" last_save="1354573520" last_save_date="2012-12-03 22:25:20.211913" stat_name="weapon_fire_count" value="22" vehicle_id="0"/>
</weapon_stat_list>
</stats>
</character>
<character id="5428010618040144225" active_profile_id="6" faction_id="2" head_id="1" title_id="80">
<stats>
<weapon_stat_list>
<weapon_stat item_id="126" last_save="1353442416" last_save_date="2012-11-20 20:13:36.0" stat_name="weapon_fire_count" value="130" vehicle_id="0"/>
<weapon_stat item_id="126" last_save="1353442416" last_save_date="2012-11-20 20:13:36.0" stat_name="weapon_play_time" value="336" vehicle_id="0"/>
<weapon_stat item_id="126" last_save="1353442416" last_save_date="2012-11-20 20:13:36.0" stat_name="weapon_score" value="570" vehicle_id="0"/>
<weapon_stat item_id="1260" last_save="1353442416" last_save_date="2012-11-20 20:13:36.099928" stat_name="weapon_fire_count" value="181" vehicle_id="0"/>
<weapon_stat item_id="1260" last_save="1353442416" last_save_date="2012-11-20 20:13:36.100053" stat_name="weapon_play_time" value="471" vehicle_id="0"/>
<weapon_stat item_id="1260" last_save="1353442416" last_save_date="2012-11-20 20:13:36.100189" stat_name="weapon_score" value="635" vehicle_id="0"/>
<weapon_stat item_id="1261" last_save="1353447137" last_save_date="2012-11-20 21:32:17.0" stat_name="weapon_fire_count" value="321" vehicle_id="0"/>
<weapon_stat item_id="1261" last_save="1353447137" last_save_date="2012-11-20 21:32:17.0" stat_name="weapon_play_time" value="442" vehicle_id="0"/>
<weapon_stat item_id="1261" last_save="1353447137" last_save_date="2012-11-20 21:32:17.0" stat_name="weapon_score" value="1228" vehicle_id="0"/>
</weapon_stat_list>
</stats>
</character>
</character_list>
```

Unique identifiers for each character weapon data record would be the combination of the Character ID, item ID, and Vehicle ID.  The type of data in the fragment is determined by the "stat_name" attribute.

The gist of the output I need is:

```
<ROW MODID="1" RECORDID="1" >
    <COL><DATA>5428010618020696081</DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA>25003</DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA>0</DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA>108</DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA>60</DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA></DATA></COL>
</ROW>
<ROW MODID="2" RECORDID="2" >
    <COL><DATA>5428010618020696081</DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA>125</DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA>0</DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA>7708</DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA></DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA>13406</DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA>62012</DATA></COL>
</ROW>
<ROW MODID="3" RECORDID="3" >
    <COL><DATA>5428010618020696081</DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA>1259</DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA>0</DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA>22</DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA></DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA></DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA></DATA></COL>
</ROW>
<ROW MODID="4" RECORDID="4" >
    <COL><DATA>5428010618040144225</DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA>126</DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA>0</DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA>130</DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA></DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA>336</DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA>570</DATA></COL>
</ROW>
<ROW MODID="5" RECORDID="5" >
    <COL><DATA>5428010618040144225</DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA>1260</DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA>0</DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA>181</DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA></DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA>471</DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA>635</DATA></COL>
</ROW>
<ROW MODID="6" RECORDID="6" >
    <COL><DATA>5428010618040144225</DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA>1261</DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA>0</DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA>321</DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA></DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA>442</DATA></COL>
    <COL><DATA>1228</DATA></COL>
</ROW>
```

There is of course more columns than that, but are omitted for simplicity.  The output example has the "fields" of Character ID, Item ID, Vehicle ID, Fire Count, Hit Count, Play Time, Score in their respective order.

This is a copy of the XSL file that I am currently using to import hit count

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/test.xsd">
        <xsl:template match="/character_list">
                <FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
                        <ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
                        <PRODUCT BUILD="" NAME="SOE API XML Import" VERSION="2.0" />
                        <DATABASE DATEFORMAT="yyyy.MM.dd" LAYOUT="" NAME="" RECORDS="" TIMEFORMAT="k:mm:ss" />
                        <METADATA>
                                <FIELD EMPTYOK="NO" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Character_ID" TYPE="TEXT" />
                                <FIELD EMPTYOK="NO" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Item_ID" TYPE="TEXT" />
                                <FIELD EMPTYOK="NO" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Vehicle_ID" TYPE="TEXT" />
                                <FIELD EMPTYOK="NO" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Value" TYPE="TEXT" />
                        </METADATA>
                        <RESULTSET>
                        <xsl:for-each select="character" >
                                <xsl:variable name="cid">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
                                </xsl:variable>
                                <xsl:for-each select="stats/weapon_stat_list/weapon_stat[@stat_name='weapon_hit_count']" >
                                        <xsl:variable name="c">
                                                <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
                                        </xsl:variable>
                                        <ROW MODID="$c" RECORDID="$c" >
                                                <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="$cid" /></DATA></COL>
                                                <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="@item_id" /></DATA></COL>
                                                <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="@vehicle_id" /></DATA></COL>
                                                <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="@value" /></DATA></COL>
                                        </ROW>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                        </RESULTSET>
                </FMPXMLRESULT>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In reading around it seems that I might need to use a for-each-group to group info together.  I'll continue to trying and figure out what I need to do to make this work, but I'm hoping that someone can save me some time.    I also don't know what version of XLST Filemaker 12 supports.  I'll keep this updated if I find out more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can iterate over all keys of the stat entries (from your comments, the keys are all `item_id`+`vehicle_id` values pairs), it should be pretty easy to aggregate all the attributes that belong to each key in one go.

From your expected output, it appears that for every key, there is exactly one `<weapon_stat>` element with `stat_name='weapon_fire_count'`. Given that this is correct, you'll easily get all `item_id` values by iterating over these `<weapon_stat>` elements:

```
<xsl:for-each select="stats/weapon_stat_list/weapon_stat[@stat_name='weapon_fire_count']" >
```

From these elements, it is straightforward to generate the output fields Item ID, Vehicle ID, and Fire Count. For the other three fields, you can select the value from the appropriate sibling with the following (a bit more advanced) XPath expression:

```
<xsl:value-of select="../weapon_stat[@stat_name='weapon_hit_count' and @item_id=current()/@item_id and @vehicle_id=current()/@vehicle_id]/@value" />
```

The trick is to compare the `@item_id` and `@vehicle_id` of the respective context nodes (these are all siblings: `../weapon_stat`) with the `@item_id` and `@vehicle_id` of the current node (which is the node selected by the `for-each` above).

All in all, you want to replace the inner `for-each` of your XSL file with this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="stats/weapon_stat_list/weapon_stat[@stat_name='weapon_fire_count']" >
    <ROW>
        <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="$cid" /></DATA></COL>
        <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="@item_id" /></DATA></COL>
        <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="@vehicle_id" /></DATA></COL>
        <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="@value" /></DATA></COL>
        <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="../weapon_stat[@stat_name='weapon_hit_count' and @item_id=current()/@item_id and @vehicle_id=current()/@vehicle_id]/@value" /></DATA></COL>
        <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="../weapon_stat[@stat_name='weapon_play_time' and @item_id=current()/@item_id and @vehicle_id=current()/@vehicle_id]/@value" /></DATA></COL>
        <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="../weapon_stat[@stat_name='weapon_score' and @item_id=current()/@item_id and @vehicle_id=current()/@vehicle_id]/@value" /></DATA></COL>
    </ROW>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Note: I omitted the `MODID` and `RECORDID` counters because there is no efficient solution to add them in this transformation. However, it is straightforward to take the result of this transformation and add the counters through a second XSL transformation.

---

Update: In the [pastebin example](http://pastebin.com/yDzMtEcL) you gave in a comment, it seems that not every key has a `weapon_fire_count` stat. So instead of iterating only over these stat entries, you need to iterate over all stats, and omit the output if there was already a preceding sibling with the same key:

```
<xsl:for-each select="stats/weapon_stat_list/weapon_stat" >
    <xsl:if test="not(boolean(preceding-sibling::weapon_stat[@item_id=current()/@item_id and @vehicle_id=current()/@vehicle_id]))">
        <ROW >
            <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="$cid" /></DATA></COL>
            <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="@item_id" /></DATA></COL>
            <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="@vehicle_id" /></DATA></COL>
            <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="../weapon_stat[@stat_name='weapon_fire_count' and @item_id=current()/@item_id and @vehicle_id=current()/@vehicle_id]/@value" /></DATA></COL>
            <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="../weapon_stat[@stat_name='weapon_hit_count' and @item_id=current()/@item_id and @vehicle_id=current()/@vehicle_id]/@value" /></DATA></COL>
            <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="../weapon_stat[@stat_name='weapon_play_time' and @item_id=current()/@item_id and @vehicle_id=current()/@vehicle_id]/@value" /></DATA></COL>
            <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="../weapon_stat[@stat_name='weapon_score' and @item_id=current()/@item_id and @vehicle_id=current()/@vehicle_id]/@value" /></DATA></COL>
        </ROW>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: There are some "gotchas" on using that though.  There is a set of entries who have weapon_id as 0 and different vehicle_id's (for context, this means the player rammed something or ran someone over with x vehicle and didn't use a weapon)  http://pastebin.com/yDzMtEcL

Comment: Actually if I understand the second part correctly it should work with:

`../weapon_stat[@stat_name='weapon_play_time' and @item_id=current()/@item_id]/@value and @vehicle_id=current()/@vehicle_id]/@value`




I'll of course test it out. :)  Thank you for helping me with this, the answer seems to be a lot simpler than I had feared or was looking into.  I just didn't know of all the options I had in xsl.

Comment: Yes, this should do the trick (except that you need to delete the `]/@value` in the middle - all three conditions should be in the same square brackets).

Comment: @Klypto: I've updated the answer to take into account that both `@item_id` and `@vehicle_id` need to be compared to find matching `weapon_stat` entries. Also, in your pastebin example, there were some stats which didn't have a `weapon_fire_count` entry. So you need a slightly different loop to not miss any entries (see lower part of the answer).

Comment: This works perfectly, and should dramatically reduce the amount of processing time.  Thank you.

Comment: (If you're interested, there's still one more level of complexity to the overall problem which I didn't even mention at all that would be the final increase in optimization, but I'm perfectly fine with the current improved state of things as it was the major bulk of what was slowing down the server's import processes).

Comment: @Klypto: Maybe you can solve it yourself with the new tricks you have learned here. Or if you are stuck again, it would be better to ask a separate question with just the remaining problem. This would make it easier for others to also benefit from your question.